# How to use visiblewhen tag with the extension <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards"> in an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse

I want to show the label i have put into the projectexplorer project -> rightClick -> new -> "MyLabel"

depending on the project type selected, the label is put by

```
 <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
                 <wizard name="My Project" category=""
            class=""
            wizardManifest="project_wizard.xml"
            id=""
            project="true"
            icon="icons/buket-16x16.png">
            <description></description>         
        </wizard>       
         <category
               id=""
               name=""
               parentCategory="">
         </category>
   </extension>
```

I have been trying to use the visiblewhen tag inside the extension tag and it doesnt work.

can someone help me to achieve this? 
thanks in advance!

Comment: The new wizard extension point does not support `visibleWhen`, you always get everything.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [Wizard Extension Markup](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdialogs_wizards_newWizards.htm) for supported attributes. VisibleWhen is not supported.
In general, If you google for the fully qualified extension name, you easily find the reference...

I find the lack of Eclipse in-IDE assistance a little frustrating.